# MediaWiki mass page rename

Tags: php, mediawiki

I need to rename all pages matching a certain pattern in MediaWiki. For any page containing XXXXX, it must be renamed to YYYYY. This includes page content as well as page names. For example, the wiki URL http://wiki.example.org/TfrmXXX_Rates should be renamed to http://wiki.example.org/TfrmYYY_Rates, and any text containing XXXXX should be replaced with YYYYY.

The [Replace Text extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3AReplace_Text) cannot be used for this, because it can only modify page content. I also need to rename the pages, and all references to them (including interwiki links).

What I have tried is this: dump the MySQL database, replace all occurrences of XXXX to YYYY, then drop and recreate the wiki database with the modified SQL script, and finally run the maintenance/rebuildall.php script (provided by MediaWiki).

The problem is that it does not work. When I search for a keyword, MediaWiki shows some hits with related page content. But when I open the URL, it shows "no content yet". I suspect that the reason for this is that some of the data is stored in PHP serialized form, and that cannot be replaced easily with a text search/replace.

So the question is: how do I rename all references in a MediaWiki database, including content and page names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finish the task. Here are the steps:

- Backup your database
- Execute this to export all page names:

  ```
  select page_title into outfile '/tmp/pagenames.txt' from page;
  ```
- I have used a program to replace all occurences that needs to be replaced, and construct another text file with the format

  ```
  oldXXXname|newXXXname
  ```

  miken's solution is equally good, if you need to replace just a single word. If you need to replace `XXX_1`, `XXX_2 XXX`, and other words that are prefixes of each other, then you need to write a program for this, and carefully select the order of replacements so they don't conflict with each other.
- Then run

  ```bash
  php maintenance/moveBatch.php --noredirects /tmp/constructed.txt
  ```
- Then use this kind of SQL to replace all other text references:

  ```sql
  use wiki_db;
  begin;
  update text set old_text =
    replace(
      replace(
        replace(
          convert(old_text using utf8), 'XXX_1', 'YYYY'
          -- and so on…
        ), 'XXX_2', 'YYYY'
      ), 'XXX_3', 'YYYY'
    ), 'XXXX_2', 'YYYY_or_whatever'
  );
  ```
- Finally, run

  ```bash
  php maintenance/rebuildall.php
  ```

I did not accept miken's answer only because it was just half of the solution.

Comment: Anybody please explain why it was downvoted? I would like to know what is wrong with this solution (that was acutally used to solve the task).

Answer (score 3):

Mediawiki is shipped with a [maintenance script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MoveBatch.php) to do the renaming of pages and any links to them. You can run this query from MySQL to populate a file called `/tmp/names.txt`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(page_title, '|', REPLACE(page_title, 'XXXXX', 'YYYYY')) INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/names.txt' FROM page WHERE page_title LIKE '%XXXXX%';
```

This will give you this file:

```
TfrmXXX_Rates|TfrmYYY_Rates
TfrmXXX_Other|TformYYY_Other
...
```

Then you should be able to run this command:

```
php /path/to/mediawiki/maintenance/moveBatch.php --noredirects /tmp/names.txt
```

The [Replace Text extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Replace_Text) should work for any other references in the text that aren't links.

Comment: Well, it seems to expect full page names. I need to replace patterns in page names instead...

Comment: Can't you just pull out a list of page names from the database and paste them into a text file?

Comment: I could rename all of the pages, now working on the text replacements.

Comment: The ReplaceText extension did not rename text in interwiki links. For example, [[foo bar XXXX foo bar]] was not renamed to [[foo bar YYYY foo bar]]. All other replacements are okay. Enabled replacement in all namespaces, for page content and page titles too. It finds the pages that needs to be changed, and it tells it has replaced them. But it does not. :-(

Comment: I just realized that there is serious problem with moveBatch.php too. It does not rename redirects. E.g. if PAGEXXX was redirected to PAGE2XXX, then moveBatch renames PAGEXXX to PAGEYYY, but it does not update the redirections. This problem has absolutely nothing to do with the --noredirects opion with moveBatch.php. :-(